# Regular Expression in Sql Server

Tags: c#, regex, sql-server-2008

I have special selection criterion for particular column and need the regular epxression for that.
e.g: A123456, S008942
this id's should get selected only
The first letter is alphabet and next 6 letters are digits.
It will always be like total of 7 letters (1Alphabet+6NumericDigits)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that solved your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SQL server pattern matching: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489%28SQL.90%29.aspx

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE [column] LIKE '[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

It is unfortunately limited, but maybe it will get what you need?

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe it helps

```
"^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}$"
```

Comment: it defines for only one letter

Comment: SELECT * FROM tblUserData WHERE ID Like '^[A-Za-z]\d{6}$' SELECT * FROM tblUserData WHERE ID Like '^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{6}$' This is also not working :(

Comment: Both the above queries are not working for me...i am using SQL server 2008

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 does not supports regular expressions

Comment: Its a simple LIKE expression i am writing ...it should work atleast

Comment: @PratikGupta, T-SQL does not support ^, $, or {}. It only supports character classes, negative character classes, % (equivalent to [.\r]*), and _ (equivalent to [.\r]).

Comment: Yes that is the reason i got lost in SQL server...But answer from Miika helped ...It solved my problem. Thanks for response though.

Answer (score 0):

This is your pattern: `[A-Z]\d{6}`
If first letter can be lowercase pattern is: `[A-Za-z]\d{6}`

`[A-Z]` means an uppercase letter.
`[A-Za-z]` means an uppercase or lowercase letter.
`\d` means a digit.
`{6}` after it means exactly 6 times. (so `\d{6}` means 6 digits)

Comment: Thanks for your response Ademiban...but its not working in the SQL query SELECT * FROM tableUserdata WHERE ID Like '[A-Z]\d{6}'

Comment: Are you sure...? try to put ^ on the start and $ at the end: `^[A-Z]\d{6}$`

Comment: This is also not working. Any conversion do i need to do before i execute this query

Comment: I haven't seen your code and can't say why it's not working but this pattern is 100% right. You can check it here: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Yes i am also sure on pattern .. there is not code actually i needed this for select statement in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Take a look on these questions:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400833/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-2008  
and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers
I think they'll help you.

Comment: Yes i got the solution ....Thanks for your help ...Writing regexp in SQL is not possible as in C#.Net, It need's to be done explicitly through code